# Good introductory book on minimal surfaces.

Tags: complex-analysis, minimal-surfaces

I briefly know that we can study minimal surfaces by three different directions, which are complex analysis, PDE and geometric measure theory. I wish to study about how complex analysis can be used to study minimal surfaces. Is there any good introductory book on this topic? Is Riemannian Geometry required to study minimal surfaces?

Comment: http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/CurveSuperfici/AG22.pdf     http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/karcher/karcherTaiwan.pdf  These two texts may be helpful.

Comment: Continued.. http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/CurveSuperfici You can find the other chapters(first link) here